Как исправить ошибку win error?
Нашел на гитхабе код для управление google dino через lego mario
Но при выполении пишется вот это:
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\SunDay\Documents\mario\mario.py", line 57
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
Found: 7D:FD:18:E4:C8:56 (LEGO Mario    )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SunDay\Documents\mario\mario.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\SunDay\Documents\mario\mario.py", line 70, in main
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Users\SunDay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\SunDay\Documents\mario\mario.py", line 47, in read_data
    await client.start_notify(LEGO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, notification_handler)
  File "C:\Users\SunDay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bleak\__init__.py", line 844, in start_notify
    await self._backend.start_notify(characteristic, wrapped_callback, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SunDay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 981, in start_notify
    await winrt_char.write_client_characteristic_configuration_descriptor_async(
OSError: [WinError -2140864497] Для чтения или записи атрибута требуется шифрование


Вот код:
import datetime
import asyncio
import struct
import sys
import time

import bleak
import pynput.keyboard

LEGO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "00001624-1212-efde-1623-785feabcd123"
SUBSCRIBE_IMU_COMMAND = bytearray([0x0A, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01])
SUBSCRIBE_RGB_COMMAND = bytearray([0x0A, 0x00, 0x41, 0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01])


class DataHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prev_y = None
        self.keyboard = pynput.keyboard.Controller()

    def xyz(self, x, y, z):
        if y > 100 and self.prev_y is not None and self.prev_y < 100:
            self.keyboard.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.space)
            time.sleep(0.3)
            self.keyboard.release(pynput.keyboard.Key.space)
        self.prev_y = y
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        timestamp = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print("[{}]\tx: {}\ty: {}\tz: {}".format(timestamp, x, y, z))

def make_handler(user_handler):
    def raw_handler(sender, data):
        if data[0] == 7:
            x, y, z = struct.unpack("bbb", data[4:7])
            user_handler(x, y, z)
    return raw_handler

async def discover():
    devices = await bleak.BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        if d.name and d.name.lower().startswith("lego mario"):
            return d

async def read_data(address, done, handler):
    async with bleak.BleakClient(address) as client:
        notification_handler = make_handler(handler)
        await client.start_notify(LEGO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, notification_handler)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        await client.write_gatt_char(LEGO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, SUBSCRIBE_IMU_COMMAND)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        await client.write_gatt_char(LEGO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, SUBSCRIBE_RGB_COMMAND)
        await done.wait()
        print('Disconnecting ...')


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    dev = loop.run_until_complete(discover())
    if dev is None:
        print("No device found")
        sys.exit(1)
    print("Found: {} ({})".format(dev.address, dev.name))
    address = dev.address

    dh = DataHandler()
    done = asyncio.Event()
    task = loop.create_task(read_data(address, done, dh.xyz))
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        done.set()

    loop.run_until_complete(task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



Что делать?
